# how to get mysql results listed in different rows by a date range?

Tags: mysql

I am having a struggle with displaying data properly on the page. I am running a query for a billing report that searches all outstanding bills and I want to display them on a single page with the outstanding balance being displayed by how old the balance is. So if client ABC has 10 invoices over the past year and some of them have outstanding balances, I would like to display those balances in columns of 0-30 / 30-60 / 60-90 / and 90+ days old. Here is what I have...

```
    $sql17 = "SELECT $mysql_billing.primary_key, $mysql_billing.a_name, $mysql_billing.invoicedate, $mysql_billing.finaltotal, $mysql_billing_dates.paidtotal,
 ($mysql_billing.finaltotal - $mysql_billing_dates.paidtotal) AS total
 FROM
   (SELECT $mysql_billing.primary_key, $mysql_billing.a_name, $mysql_billing.login_username, $mysql_billing.invoicedate,
   SUM($mysql_billing.custotal) AS finaltotal 
   FROM $mysql_billing where $today >= invoicedate AND $start_search_prev180_date <= invoicedate AND custotal != payments GROUP BY login_username) $mysql_billing 
 LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT $mysql_billing_dates.id, $mysql_billing_dates.username, 
   SUM($mysql_billing_dates.amount) AS paidtotal 
   FROM $mysql_billing_dates where complete != 'yes' GROUP BY username) $mysql_billing_dates 
 ON ($mysql_billing.login_username = $mysql_billing_dates.username) 
 GROUP BY a_name ORDER BY a_name ASC";
```

this seems to print out the results but how do you get the results into different columns based off of more than 1 date variable? Do I have to do 4 separate queries?

Comment: are you doing this in PHP?  I'd guess you'd want to loop over the 4 date ranges in PHP, running your query with the date variable each time and putting the results into arrays for display.

Comment: The query and the DB structure isn't that clear. Can you please set up an SQL fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: ok, I did that. I think my query is messed up though since the results are not even what I want. Here is the link. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f49b/3/0

Comment: basically, def1 should show a balance of 621.52 for a 90+ date choice and abc1 should show 44.6 balance with a 90+ date choice

Comment: Where is the complete column?  "complete != 'yes'

Comment: i took it out since it is not that important to get this working

Comment: Can you tell me how you get your balance of 44.6 for abc -- when I subtract those values from billing_dates (which I presume are the payments), I get 119.29

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct, 119.29 it should be but i have nulls showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL Fiddle was close, but a few of your joins were incorrect.

```
SELECT 
  billing.a_name, 
  billing.finaltotal, 
  billing_dates.paidtotal,
  (billing.finaltotal - billing_dates.paidtotal) AS total,
   billing.TimePeriod
FROM
   (SELECT 
      a_name, 
      login_username, 
      SUM(custotal) AS finaltotal,
      CASE 
        WHEN invoicedate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN '30'
        WHEN invoicedate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) THEN '60'
        WHEN invoicedate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN '90'
        ELSE '90+'
      END AS TimePeriod

    FROM billing 
    where CURDATE() >= invoicedate 
      AND CAST(20120601 AS DATETIME) <= invoicedate 
    GROUP BY login_username) billing 
 LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT 
      username, 
      SUM(amount) AS paidtotal 
    FROM billing_dates
    GROUP BY username) billing_dates 
   ON (billing.a_name = billing_dates.username) 
ORDER BY a_name ASC;
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc83cc/1).

Comment: so now that it is pulling the correct values, how to display this in 4 columns based off the invoicedate results?

Comment: Please see edits to answer and fiddle above.  Good luck -- this should get you going in the right direction.  Assuming the hard coded date is actually today, then this will work (I updated your table defs to get different results as well)

Comment: got most of it worked out, the NULL stuff. Just trying now to include results that are present in billing but not in billing_dates

Comment: so if I remove the line below, it pulls all results from both tables which is what I want. if there is someone in billing, but not in billing_dates, it still shows them with 0.00 balance. sounds correct?
      AND CAST(20120601 AS DATETIME) <= invoicedate

Comment: ok, so I ran into a problem that hopefully you know. If the billing_dates have 2 rows for a user and only 1 is paid (IE: the 1st row), the case when invoicedate snippet only looks at the first row in the table to display the 30/60/90. It does pull the dollar amount properly, but how is it supposed to recognize the 2nd row of data and use that for the 30/60/90?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend selecting all the outstanding invoices for the client and then using code to organize those into lists for each of the time periods.

Using a single query for this is likely to be faster and it's easy to categorize the results in your program.

Then you just pick one element per list to produce the lines in the report.

Comment: would you have any examples of this process?